# How to back to app after navigation is done

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity which is used to start navigation in google maps app. 
When the destination is almost reached I'd like to receive a notification pressing that will open my app. 
I should use pending intent. it's okay. I don't really undestand how manage notification when the destination is almost reached?

Should I use some kind of services to track current location and send pending intent? The navigation could lasts several hours and Android Oreo kills services

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start a service when you start the navigation and check after 2-3 sec is it reached to destination . if yes then raise a self notification from server end or your end using this code .

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        //Create the intent that’ll fire when the user taps the notification//

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.androidauthority.com/"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("My notification");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

using this can send notification.
this help me pls use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service and track location passively with usage [PRIORITY_NO_POWER](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_NO_POWER) (it would be updating by google maps) and when location is close enough to target - show your notification.

Comment: Will this service stay alive while my app is in background?

Comment: @YaSi you can use `startForeground()` to be sure. Without foreground notification system can kill it in some conditions.

Comment: thanx. 
I'm also going to try GeoFencing API cause having notification above navigation screen isn't really expected behavior for users

Answer (score 0):

the best way is GeoFences API.
While another app (such Google Maps retrieve new locations) geoclient in your app wait to be informed when location reached destination. In that case your app can fire notification whether being in background or entirely closed